# How to add video to playlist by clicking on button with source

Tags: javascript, html, video, playlist

I have a problem, I want to add a video by button with source onto playlist. Something like... During the first video plays, there are 3 buttons with mp4 sources. When I click on that buttons, they start playing. Everything works, but I don´t want that thing. I want to make a function when I onclick on a button, video starts playing after the first video. Something like flowplayer - http://flash.flowplayer.org/demos/plugins/javascript/playlist/dynamic.html 
function add to position 2.

```
<body>

    <div style="overflow: hidden;">
        <video id="video" width="80%" autoplay controls >
            <source id="videoSource" src="video/0.mp4" type="video/mp4">

        </video>

        <a class="btn blue" onclick="changevideo0()">0</a>
        <a class="btn blue" onclick="changevideo1()">1</a>
        <a class="btn blue" onclick="changevideo2()">2</a>
    </div>



    <script>

        function changevideo0() {
        document.getElementById('video').src = "video/0.mp4";}

        function changevideo1() {
        document.getElementById('video').src = "video/1.mp4";}

        function changevideo2() {
        document.getElementById('video').src = "video/2.mp4";}


    </script>


</body>
```

Comment: Use a combination of [this](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) and [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_duration.asp). First get the video duration, set a timer to expire after the duration and set the new video and start playing. For the function, I would just recommend adding the source to a queue list (array) and pop the first element off when the timer expires and repeat the process

Comment: Thanks, I will be trying to manage this ... But I don't know, if I am too skillfull to do that :)

Answer (score 0):

I changed your function slightly because it is not efficient to add that many functions just to change one part of it.

Your code was pretty good, just pointing to the wrong element.

```js
        function changevideo(source) {
          document.getElementById('videoSource').src = source;
        }
```

```html
<body>

    <div style="overflow: hidden;">
        <video id="video" width="80%" autoplay controls >
            <source id="videoSource" src="video/0.mp4" type="video/mp4">

        </video>

        <a class="btn blue" onclick="changevideo('video/0.mp4')">0</a>
        <a class="btn blue" onclick="changevideo('video/1.mp4')">1</a>
        <a class="btn blue" onclick="changevideo('video/2.mp4')">2</a>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, that seems right and logic, but doesn't work.

Comment: It works right here: https://output.jsbin.com/zihehedafu, if you observe the generated source when you click each number, the `src` attribute updates. What happens on your end?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider the following example as logic code, as I have not tested, checked for syntax errors and noor do I know from the top of my head if I should get the length of the video from the source or player element in HTML.

```
<body>
    <script>
        var player = document.getElementById("video");

        var videolist = {
          'video/0.mp4',
          'video/1.mp4',
          'video/2.mp4'
        };

        var queuelist = {};

        function changevideo() {
          if(!queuelist.length == 0){
            document.getElementById('videoSource').src = queuelist.shift();
            setTimeout(changevideo, player.length * 1000);
          } else {
            alert("no more video's in queue");
          }
        }

        player.play();
        setTimeout('changevideo', player.length * 1000);
    </script>

    <div style="overflow: hidden;">
        <video id="video" width="80%" autoplay controls >
            <source id="videoSource" src="video/0.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>

        <a class="btn blue" onclick="queuelist.append(0)">0</a>
        <a class="btn blue" onclick="queuelist.append(1)">1</a>
        <a class="btn blue" onclick="queuelist.append(2)">2</a>
    </div>
</body>
```